# Cauchy product but do not work

Tags: calculus

I try to get the following sum
$$a(n)=\sum _{k=0}^n c(k) B_{n-k} \binom{n}{k}$$
separating in two as Cauchy product
$$f(x) g(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^n a(k) x^n$$
where
$$g(x)=\sum _{k=0}^n B_k x^k$$ and 
$$f(x)=\sum _{k=0}^n c(k) \binom{n}{k}x^k$$
but do not work I think it is cause de Binomial depent of n
??

Comment: This looks like a job for exponential generating functions.  $\frac{a(n)}{n!} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{c(k)}{k!} \cdot \frac{B_{n-k}}{(n-k)!}$.

Comment: thanks @Daniel Schepler